# Wicket http post, get raw data from servletrequest?

Tags: ajax, servlets, post, wicket

I try do POST some data to a Wicket WebPage. This works fine if the data is in a form. However, I want to post the data with jQuery's ajax-post. I am unable to get this data in my Page-constructor.

This is my jquery command:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    cache: false,
                    url: "http://localhost:8888/testjson",
                    data: JSON.stringify({"aap":"noot"),

                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(ydata){alert("aap");},
                    failure: function(errMsg) {alert(errMsg);},
                        contentType: false,
                    dataType: "json"
                });
```

The /testjson is a mounted WebPage.

```
public TestJsonApiPage( PageParameters pp )
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray( ( (ServletWebRequest) TestJsonApiPage.this.getRequest() ).getContainerRequest().getInputStream() );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the constructor. What I see happening is that the inputstream is empty. However, when debugging, I see the raw data that I posted in `HttpServletRequest` in the `newWebRequest` in my `WicketApplication`

**tl;dr** How to get the raw post data in Wicket Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `Page` does something to the post-parameters.

The solution for my problem is to use a Resource.

```
    public class MyResource extends AbstractResource
    @Override
    protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse( Attributes attributes )
    {

        ResourceResponse resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse();
        resourceResponse.setContentType( "text/json" );
        resourceResponse.setTextEncoding( "utf-8" );

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) attributes.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

        try
        {
            this.json = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream() );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resourceResponse.setWriteCallback( new WriteCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void writeData( Attributes attributes ) throws IOException
            {
                OutputStream outputStream = attributes.getResponse().getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter( outputStream );


                writer.write( MyResource.this.json );
                writer.close();
            }
        } );

        return resourceResponse;
    }
```

Comment: How do you attach a URL to this resource?

Comment: By mounting it. See also this excellent article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-implement-rss-feeds-custom

Comment: But it seems it is not possible to do this when the resource/page requires authorization? Seems we have to wait for Wicket 7 to support that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5012

Comment: Ok... so even though the article mentioned in my previous comment suggests that resources are not authorized, my testing suggests they are... BUT it also seems that even with a resource the PageParameters still swallow the input stream... I am now suspecting the parameters in the mount path to be doing this. Will test without any parameters in the mount path and report back.

Comment: It indeed was the parameter in the mount path. If you map to a mount path that does not have parameters in it then Wicket leaves the input stream alone. Also, I found out why it seemed that the page was still being authorized. It is because in our setup we are using Container Managed Authentication. So in fact the container (Tomcat in our case) was intercepting requesst to the resource when you were not logged in. This is in fact ok for us.