# How should I handle arbitrary AJAX requests in Wicket 7?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket

I've managed to replicate this [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get) for jQuery AJAX [using Resource mounting in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874695/wicket-http-post-get-raw-data-from-servletrequest).

However, I still want to know if there are better ways of handling arbitrary AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want low-level control over what you're sending. [`AbstractAjaxBehavior`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AbstractAjaxBehavior.html) is probably more or less what you're looking for. You can do something like

```
public class MyAjaxBehavior extends AbstractAjaxBehavior{
    @Override
    public void onRequest() {
        RequestCycle.get().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(
                new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8", "{myVal:123}")
        );
    }
};
```

You can replace the `TextRequestHandler` with some other request handler (or write your own) to return exactly the data you want.

If you wish to write your own javascript handling the ajax you can look at the [Wicket Ajax wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax), where it describes how this ajax is to be invoked manually (you can get the callback URL via [`AbstractAjaxBehavior#getCallbackUrl()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AbstractAjaxBehavior.html#getCallbackUrl())).

If all you really want is just updating the display - high-level ajax for updating wicket components is what you want. Most Wicket Ajax behaviors (like [`AjaxEventBehavior`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html)) attach their own ajax invocation, you don't have to do the javascript side of things at all. All you need to do is add components to the provided [`AjaxRequestTarget`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html), and wicket will do the rest, updating what the component displays automatically.

Both of these methods will access the page however, and if that is not what you want, resource mounting is the way to go.

Comment: I've tried a bit of AbstractAjaxBehavior and AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.

Comment: *Continuing on from previous. Accidental enter pressed*

Comment: *Again* Anyways, even with the callbackURL being explicitly hardcoded into the page's HTML, I find myself receiving the page markup instead of the test message that the behavior was suppose to send back to the client.

Comment: That only happens if the Wicket's AJAX kicks in, which is the case for most behaviors, like `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` (which I have mistakenly put next to `AbstractAjaxBehavior`, and they don't really do the same thing). I've amended the answer with an example of how you could return some raw data.