# Call Wicket 6 Code from Javascript and return value

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, wicket-6

I have managed to call my Wicket 6 Java code from Javascript using option A in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612027/1047418

However, I have not been able to find examples for returning data from the Java side back to JavaScript (the generated JavaScript callback function does not even include a return statement). How can this be achieved?

Edit: I am not trying to set an attribute in Java and as I've already explained, calling Wicket from JavaScript is not the problem here. I am trying to *return a JSON object from Wicket back to the browser as a result of an Ajax request*.

Edit2: Following martin-g's examples I cobbled up this working example...

Java

```
public class MyAjaxBehaviour extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

    @Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
        super.onComponentTag(tag);
        tag.put("aprachatcallbackurl", getCallbackUrl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.setDataType("json");
        attributes.setWicketAjaxResponse(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        getComponent().getRequestCycle().replaceAllRequestHandlers(
            new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8", "{...JSON GOES HERE...}));
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
var mySuccessCallback = function(param1, param2, data, statusText) {
    // Data contains the parsed JSON object from MyAjaxBehaviour.respond(...)
    ...
}

var myFailureCallback = function() {
    ...
}

Wicket.Ajax.get({
    "u": callbackUrl,
    "dt": "json",
    "wr": false,
    "sh": [mySuccessCallback],
    "fh": [myFailureCallback]
});
```

Main problem as that the Wicket 7 Reference incorrectly instructs to use "wr" instead of "dt" in the JavaScript call. :)

Comment: RobAu, the other way around. I need to return a JSON object from Wicket to the browser as a response to an Ajax request.

Comment: You need to request an url from the (Wicket) application that returns some JSON data? You can just create and mount a `Resource` and link to that then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it in a simpler way!

Wicket Ajax API is just: `Wicket.Ajax.ajax({...})`. All you need to prepare at the server side is to save the callback url, e.g. by saving it globally in the `window` object or in HTML element's attributes (`data-the-url`).

```
public class CallFromJavascriptBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {
   @Override
   protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      final StringValue parameterValue = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getQueryParameters().getParameterValue("yourName");
      System.out.println(String.format("Hello %s", parameterValue.toString()));

      // write anything to the WebResponse and then consume it in the JS success handler. See below
   }

   @Override
   public void onComponenntTag(ComponenntTag tag, Component component) {
       super.onComponenntTag(tag, component);
       tag.put("data-the-url", getCallbackUrl());
   }
}
```

Then in your JS code you can do:

```
var callbackUrl = jQuery("#theElementId").data("the-url");
Wicket.Ajax.get({"u": callbackUrl, "sh":[successHandler], "fh": [failureHandler] });
```

Where `successHandler` and `failureHandler` are JS functions defined inline (e.g. `function(...) {}`) or elsewhere.

More documentation you can find at:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_ajax_request_attributes_and_call_listeners

A blog article with an complete example at http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-javascript-improvements/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "write anything to the WebResponse" part? I've tried to set the Ajax data type to "json" in the Wicket.Ajax.get parameters and updateAjaxAttributes(...) method but what gets sent is "{...json...}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajax-response></ajax-response>" resulting in a parse error.

Comment: Wait, I got it. The wicket guide has an error. It says "use parameter 'wr' for data type" when the correct one is "dt"... https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_ajax_request_attributes_and_call_listeners

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a Resource and mount it, and get it with your favorite Ajax-approach.

For example:

```
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource
    @Override
    protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse( Attributes attributes )
    {

        ResourceResponse resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse();
        resourceResponse.setContentType( "text/json" );
        resourceResponse.setTextEncoding( "utf-8" );

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) attributes.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

        try
        {
            this.json = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream() );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resourceResponse.setWriteCallback( new WriteCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void writeData( Attributes attributes ) throws IOException
            {
                OutputStream outputStream = attributes.getResponse().getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter( outputStream );


                writer.write( MyResource.this.json );
                writer.close();
            }
        } );

        return resourceResponse;
    }
```

(Copied from my other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876029/461499)

And see here for mounting it:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-implement-rss-feeds-custom